# How to do jq arithmetic under Windows

Tags: windows, jq

I am reading the `jq` manual and it says, that `+` and `-` operations on number should "just work". However, I can't seem to be able to use them in almost any operation, for example, in object construction

Given `input.json` as `{"a": 4}`

this command:

```
jq "6-.a" input.json
```

produces

```
2
```

but this command:

```
jq "{b: 6-.a}" input.json
```

produces

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '}' (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
{b: 6-.a}     
jq: 1 compile error
```

How to work this around? Thanks

Comment: Use parentheses around the expression `jq "{b: (6-.a)}" input.json`

Comment: cool, please make it an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [constructing objects](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction%3A%7B%7D) with expressions as key or value, the expression needs to be surrounded by parentheses:

```bash
jq "{b: (6-.a)}" input.json
```

```json
{
  "b": 2
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uruJW0VTop8)